# Binding image lazy loading to new images inserted after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I'm using Mika Tuupola's Lazy Load plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload to delay loading images as you scroll down a long image gallery. The problem is after 10 images, I use infinite scrolling so I fetch the next 10 images, and append them via ajax. Lazy Loading no longer works on this next batch of appended images.

It's a pretty javascript-heavy image gallery, so for everything else (such as tooltips, modal overlays, etc) I've been using jQuery's delegate() to bind to ajax-inserted elements. The problem with the Lazy Load plugin is that I'm not sure what *event* to bind to.

So say I want to lazy load images with a class of "lazy". I would write this:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
    effect: "fadeIn" 
});
```

and it works for the first 10 images, but stops working after inserting more via ajax. The only thing I can think of is to use delegate on a **load** event, like so:

```
$(document).delegate("img.lazy", "load", function(event) {  
    $(this).lazyload({ 
         effect: "fadeIn" 
    });     
});
```

but that breaks everything. 
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The jQuery I use to load more records (this is a Rails app):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var url;
    url = $(".pagination .next_page").attr("href");
    if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
    $(".pagination").html("<p>loading more images...</p>");
    return $.getScript(url);
    }
});

$(window).scroll();
```

Comment: @Fresheyeball .on with what event? That's what he's asking.

Comment: why not try using `.on` on lazyload? wouldn't that work?

Comment: @rgin Again, with what event? `lazyload` isn't an event, and `.on` requires an event to bind to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use the `ajaxStop` method.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
    effect: "fadeIn" 
}).removeClass("lazy");
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
        effect: "fadeIn" 
    }).removeClass("lazy");
});
```

`removeClass` prevents double initialization.

Comment: Wow, thank you that worked like a charm. Now I just need to understand how exactly `ajaxStop()` solved the problem (I read this http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ but still a bit confused). Is it performance-friendly?

Comment: It is performance friendly, however it would be even better if you instead placed it in the callback of the specific ajax request that is updating the page.

Comment: @DelPiero - extending Kevin B's comment. The deferreds object is your friend in this scenario. See: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kevin B's answer if you want to avoid `ajaxStop` jQuery now defines a `when()` function for that purpose

```
// the following code will be executed when the ajax request resolve.
// the ajax function must return the value from calling the $.ajax() method.

    $.when(load_new_image(1), load_new_image(2), load_new_image(3)).done(function(i1, i2, i3){

            if($('img.lazy').length){

                 $('img.lazy').lazyload({ 

                          effect:'fadeIn'

                 }).removeClass('lazy').addClass('lazyloaded');

            }

        });

        function load_new_image(image_id) {

            return $.ajax({
                url: "someUrl",
                dataType: "json",
                data:  yourJsonData,            
                ...
            });
        }
```

from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/