# Jquery LazyLoad not working on ajax generated images and outputted in tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-lazyload

I am using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload but it is not working for an image result tabs that is generated by php loop and outputted using jquery ajax serializearray on bootstrap tabs. So I tried to put these codes in ajax success function and together with the output as  but nothing worked.

```
$("#container").one("click", function() {
  $("#container").load("images.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
     $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });              
});
```

Source: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_ajax.html

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
    effect: "fadeIn" 
}).removeClass("lazy");
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
   $("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
       effect: "fadeIn" 
   }).removeClass("lazy");
});
```

Source: [Binding image lazy loading to new images inserted after ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035985/binding-image-lazy-loading-to-new-images-inserted-after-ajax-request?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Thanks for the help!

**Update**

Part of the problem is found by setting the container. This code is added in ajax success function.

```
                           $("img.lazy").lazyload({
                                threshold : 100,
                                effect : "fadeIn",
                                container: $(".resulttab, .resulttab2")
                            }); 
                            $('.resulttab, .resulttab2').trigger('scroll');
```

Then this one is added in document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
      effect: "fadeIn"
   }).removeClass("lazy");
})
```

Now the remaining problem is, the images in the other tab. The images don't load unless I scroll the page. I tried to trigger scroll when the tab is clicked but it didn't work. This is what I tried but both didn't work.

```
 //Attempt one
 $( "#display" ).on( "tabsbeforeload", function( event, ui ) {
     $('.resulttab').trigger('scroll'); 
 })
 //Attempt two 
 function triggerscroll() {
      $('.resulttab').trigger('scroll'); 
 }
```